# Unhandled exception: Exit code -1073740940

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to get my first Flutter application running but I keep running into this error. I ran the flutter doctor but it didn't find any errors.

Can someone help me out? Google couldn't.

I got this result for both my phone and the emulator.

```
Unhandled exception:
Exit code -1073740940 from:     C:\Users\pj_he\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s RF8M52H6GFM     shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
#0      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:360:7)
#1      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:289:10)
#2      AndroidDevice.lastLogcatTimestamp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:517:27)
#3      _AdbLogReader._start (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:697:41)
#4      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:805:24)
#5      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:213:7)
#6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:818:19)
#7      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:472:9)
#8      FlutterDevice.startEchoingDeviceLog (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:324:38)
#9      FlutterDevice.runHot     (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:367:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:253:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppDomain.startApp.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:392:23)
#12     AppDomain.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:452:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good evening. So as adb.exe is a part of android sdk platform-tools, for me help updating platform-tools for new version from 29.0.0 to 29.0.1.
Maybe reloading this part will be also helpful. If u are using android studio you can navigate as **Settings > System Settings > Android SDK > (Tab SDK Tools)**. Try this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up on this question by searching for the same error code and had exactly the same issue. I can confirm that updating the SDK platform tools to 29.0.1 resolves the error.